# How to get data out from node 'request' module

Tags: node.js, request

I am using request module to request inside 'express post router' in NodeJS.
I can get 'price' value inside request well.
But I want to use that out of request, like the position in which console.log(price) is. 
but it says price is not defined that is in console.log
How can I pull that out of request to use with another way?

```
exports.clientOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    const { clientID, riderID, clientOrder } = req.body;

    await request(
      {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://api2....',
        body: data,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
      },
      async (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
          return next(error);
        }
        const price = Math.imul(totalDistance / 1000, 2000);

      },
    );

    // I want to get price value here out of request.
    console.log(price) 
    return res.send('order finished well');
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` only works with a `thenable`, you can wrap `request` action to a Promise like this:

```
exports.clientOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    const { clientID, riderID, clientOrder } = req.body;

    const price = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(
        {
          method: 'POST',
          uri: 'https://api2....',
          body: data,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
        },
        (error, response) => {
          if (error) {
            return reject(error);
          }
          const price = Math.imul(totalDistance / 1000, 2000); // ???
          resolve(price);
        },
      );
    });

    // I want to get price value here out of request.
    console.log(price)
    return res.send('order finished well');
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: really thank you so much. But I didn't understand well about await with thenable. In my post, async and await request doesn't have any problem, but when I use your way that you responsed, await works only thenable?

Comment: In Javascript, a thenable is a `object` what include `.then()` function. Example, a promise is a `thenable` (`myPromise.then()....`). In `await request` line, your `await` does not make sense, because `request()` return a void (callback style). In simple, `await` works with a Promise.

Comment: thank you so much. and then, if i want to use async await at (error, response) arrow function in request, I have to use also new promise there?

Comment: @DDDD Yes, `request` is a lib what has been written by `callback` style, you have to wrap it into a Promise. This method works for any `callback style` libs. Or, you can find `Promise` version of the libs, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise , now you can use it in a simple way, like `const res = await request(options)`

Comment: Thank you so much!